# uidatetimepicker: how to prevent typing in invalid date

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In all examples here:

```
https://rawgit.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker/master/example/index.html
```

while you obviously can't select an invalid date from the picker you still can type in an invalid date string in the edit box.
I'm looking for ways to either prevent the user from typing in an invalid date. Be it disabling the edit field altogether and leaving only the picker portion or installing a handler to catch invalid dates.

Comment: Can't you add `readonly` to the `input`?

Comment: I was able to do that. But after seeing what it looks like - dispappointed with the look and feel. It looks as if the whole thing (including the picker) is disabled, even though its not.